# Express the dimensions of the null space and range space of $S$ and $T$ in terms of $\dim V , \dim W$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I need to solve the following problem.

> Let $V$ and $W$ be finite dimensional vector spaces and let $S\colon V \to W$ and $T\colon W \to V$ be linear maps such that $ST=I_v ={\rm identity}$.  Express the dimensions of the null space and range space of $S$ and $T$ in terms of $\dim V, \dim W$.

**My attempt**

Let $\dim V=n $ and $\dim W=m$. Since $ST=I_v$, nullity of $S=0$. Thus $\operatorname{rank}(S)=\dim W=m$.

But how do I find that of $T$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $ST=\operatorname{Id}$, $\ker T=\{0\}$ and, in particular, $\dim\ker T=0$. So, $\dim T(W)=\dim W$.

On the other hand, since $ST=\operatorname{Id}$, $S(V)=W$ and therefore $\dim S(V)=\dim W$. And then, by the rank-nullity theorem,$$\dim\ker S=\dim V-\dim S(V)=\dim V-\dim W.$$

Comment: how $ \ ST=Id  \Rightarrow ker (T)=\{0\} \ $ ? Can you show little more?

Comment: @yourmath If $T.v=0$, then$$v=\operatorname{Id}.v=(ST).v=s.(T.v)=S.0=0.$$

Comment: lastly, how $ \ ST==I_v \Rightarrow S(V)=W \ \ i.e. S \ onto \ $ ? please do this little

Comment: @yourmath If $w\in W$, then$$w=\operatorname{Id}.w=(ST).w=S.(T.w).$$